# How can I find inexpensive salvage repair (frame) parts?

Tags: repair, parts, full-suspension

I've got a 2008 or 2009 Titus X. I cracked one of the struts (probably the wrong term) in the rear suspension triangle.

I'm hoping I can find a salvage part (still waiting to see how expensive a new part will be if it's not covered under warranty).

My first thought is Ebay but I thought there might be better places. Is there such a thing as a "junkyard for bikes" by mail? How can I find where to look for salvage repair parts?

Comment: Scan Ebay and Craig's List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this bike you may be able to get replacement seatstays or chainstays from the manufacturer.  See their frame parts section of their store or give them a call.

http://shop.titusti.com/category-s/1836.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check for a local Cycle-Recycle or for one of the many charity bike centers.Some of the charity centers teach local youth bike repairs and they earn a bike in the process.